# Make SQL Azure database as read only using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database

I need to make SQL azure database as readonly using PowerShell script.
How can we do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TSQL command [alter database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx) like so,

```
ALTER DATABASE [Foo] SET  READ_ONLY WITH NO_WAIT
```

You can execute the statement via quite few a ways: `sqlcmd`, Sql Server's Powershell provider and .Net's System.Data.SqlClient classes.

Comment: Can you provide the powershell script for running this command on sql azure?

Comment: @sudhirk Show some effort instead of gimme teh codez approach and you might get more assistance.

Answer (score 2):

I have created following PS script for making databae readonly for some time. This could be helpful to anyone who are looking for this type of solution.

```
Add-AzureAccount

$subscription = "subscriptioname";
$serverName = "servername";
$database = "dbname";
$userid = "user@servername";
$password = "password";
$sleeptimeinsecond = 120;

Select-AzureSubscription $subscription

# Create DB connection
$connectionString = "Server=tcp:$serverName.database.windows.net;
Database=master;User ID=$userid;
Password=$password;Trusted_Connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True;" 
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()
echo '**connection opened'

# Run readonly command on database
$command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
$command.Connection = $connection
$command.CommandText = "ALTER DATABASE $database SET READ_ONLY"
$reader = $Command.ExecuteReader()
echo '**command executed'
echo "**Database is now in readonly state"


$reader.Close()
$connection.Close()
echo '**reader & connection object closed'

#sleep for some time till process is going on.
echo "**Sleeping for $sleeptimeinsecond seconds..."
Start-Sleep $sleeptimeinsecond
echo '**Awake from sleep'

#reopen connection
$connection.Open()

# Run read_write command on database
$command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
$command.Connection = $connection
$command.CommandText = "ALTER DATABASE $database SET READ_WRITE"
$reader = $Command.ExecuteReader()
echo '**command executed'
echo "**Database is now in read_write state"

$reader.Close()
$connection.Close()
echo '**reader & connection object closed'
echo '**Script execution done'
```